# Divergence of a 2d vector.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces, vector-fields

The formula for calculating the divergence at a point in a vector field is not clear to me.

$$\mathbf{v} = [V_x, V_y]$$

here $V$ is a vector and $V_x$ and $V_y$ are its $x$ and $y$ components.

Actual Divergence Equation is as follows
$$\text{Divergence}(\mathbf{v}(x ,y)) = \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}$$

but I feel it should be

$$\text{Divergence}(\mathbf{v}(x,y)) = \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}$$

means calculating partial derivative of $x$ with whole vector(instead of $x$ component of the vector) and partial derivative of $y$ with whole vector(instead of $y$ component of the vector).

I am looking for a better explanation.

Thanks

Comment: If you could explain why you think it should have four terms (e.g. "I think divergence should do X, and I feel like the 4-term expression would be the way to do that"), then it could be refuted in an answer. But without your thoughts, this is kind of impossible to answer

Comment: What definition of divergence are you using to propose a different expression?  Further, if you already know that your alternative is incorrect, then what's your actual question?

Comment: @MarkS.I I think my interpretation of divergence should be correct because the output of lets say the first term of the vector $v_x$ is influenced by both x and y and not only x, similarly for the 2nd term $v_y$. That's why we need to have 4 terms considering change in both x and y with respect to the first vector term $v_x$ and the second vector term $v_y$. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: @BrianMoehring like explained in the comment to Mark, I feel  the output of lets say the first term of the vector $v_x$ is influenced by both x and y and not only x, similarly for the 2nd term $v_y. And to your question " if you already know that your alternative is incorrect, then what's your actual question?"   I am looking for an explanation to why my interpretation of divergence is incorrect(If it really is)?

Comment: Nobody is arguing against the possibility both $V_x$ and $V_y$ can depend on both $x$ and $y$.  This doesn't impact the definition of the divergence.

Comment: The 4-term expression certainly includes how $v_x$ depends on $y$, and is a reasonable thing to calculate (maybe we could call it the "Pratham-vergence"). But I can't really explain why it's not the definition of divergence without an idea of what you feel the divergence should be. For example, if you feel the divergence should somehow measure outward force on a small rubber band in a fluid, I could show you why divergence works and Pratham-vergence fails. But if all you can say is that you feel divergence needs all 4 terms, then all I can say is that mathematicians chose something different.

Comment: Definitions can be neither true nor false. What is true or false is whether the definition you set forth satisfies any interesting properties. Perhaps, but not the ones that the usual divergence satisfies.